# Repeating controls in windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a Windows Forms application to generate incentive reports for staff in different groups. In order to match the report template, I need to manually put controls in the form for only one staff. If I finished all the logic inside, how can I make it dynamic so that it could auto generate reports for all the staff by using same template?

Comment: WPF would be much better suited for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using SQL Server Reporting Services? This plugs into Visual Studio nicely and makes reporting very simple. It is a great option if your business already has a SQL Server license.

Also, it is very difficult to give a detailed technical response without any technical details about the way in which you are implementing these templates/reports/forms. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it dynamically, you can setup a database in which information about the controls required for a staff member will be stored. Now while the form loads, you can check what alterations need to be done for a particular staff member, over and above the template.

Hope this helps ! For more details, you will need to post some code snippets and would be able to help in details.